# Access/VB Custom Navigation Buttons - Go To Next/Prev by date

Tags: vba, ms-access, navigation, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I have a form that our supervisors use to enter their shifts by manufacture line, daily.  My subform (based on a query) shows all of the entered shifts by date (I have a search box, where you can select a date).
My navigation buttons (currently just run by macro for Go To First, Next, Last) do what they are supposed to - which is move to the next/previous record, but I'm wondering if there is a way to code my buttons to move to the next set of records by date, instead of moving just to the next record within the current date?

For example, when I search 9/28/17 in my date search box, my subform populates 57 records for that date.  My current Next & Previous buttons just move one by one on each record in that date, before moving along to the next date (which, of course, is what the macro is telling it to do!). I'd love to be able to hit Next and have it jump to 9/29/17.  Not sure if this is even possible with a macro, but maybe with some VB code?

I'm using Access 2010 / VB.  My single form saves data to a single table.  My subform pulls from a Query and is displayed in datasheet view.
Form Name - ShiftRecord2.
Subform - ShiftProdRecords2_Query_subform.
Subform currently populates by ShiftDate.
I have my main form and subform linked through Master/Child field of ShiftDate.

I'm not sure what all you need to see on my end to be able to help.  I appreciate any and all help/tips/advice/tutorials/links!

Edit to add:
My current filter field on my subform looks like this:

```
[ShiftDate] Like "*" & [Forms]![ShiftRecord2]![txtSearchDate] & "*"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have an existing filter field, please provide it's name and the filter. Possibly, you can just increment or decrement that filter field.

Comment: Thank you! I love this site - it has been so helpful! Currently, my subform filter looks like this:   [ShiftDate] Like "*" & [Forms]![ShiftRecord2]![txtSearchDate] & "*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have my main form and subform linked through Master/Child field of
>   ShiftDate.

Then:

> My current filter field on my subform looks like this:

```
[ShiftDate] Like "*" & [Forms]![ShiftRecord2]![txtSearchDate] & "*"
```

If so, *remove* the filter and use Erik's idea for your buttons, and then filter the *parent* form:

```
Me!txtSearchDate.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, Me!txtSearchDate.Value)
Me.Filter = "ShiftDate = #" & Format(Me!txtSearchDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

and:

```
Me!txtSearchDate.Value = DateAdd("d", 1, Me!txtSearchDate.Value)
Me.Filter = "ShiftDate = #" & Format(Me!txtSearchDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

No requery is needed. The Master/Child link will requery the subform automatically.

Comment: This is absolutely PERFECT!  Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

Next:

```
Me.txtSearchDate = DateAdd("d",1, Me.txtSearchDate,)
Me.mySubformName.Requery
```

Previous:

```
Me.txtSearchDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Me.txtSearchDate)
Me.mySubformName.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you both so much for taking the time to help me! I'm going to try these out in the morning! I appreciate you!!